# how do I install ruby-mode for emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs, ruby-mode

I have just installed emacs for fedora.I want to use `emacs` to write `ruby`. What are the tools,extensions needed that provide me code hinting,code completion type features for ruby ?

Answer (score 8):

`ruby-mode` is already included from Emacs 23 onwards. It's also available via ELPA though. Some other things you might be interested in are integrating RVM, `feature-mode` (Cucumber), `rspec-mode`, `ruby-electric`, `inf-ruby`, `rinari` (for Rails) etc. Here's my current Emacs configuration for Ruby development:

https://github.com/citizen428/emacs.d/blob/master/config/ruby-conf.el

I also wrote a blog post on this topic once, it's a bit outdated and my config has changed since then, but it's better documented and maybe helps you in getting started:

http://www.citizen428.net/blog/2010/07/06/emacs-for-rubyists

If you use `yasnippet` you can find Ruby completions here: https://github.com/bmaland/yasnippet-ruby-mode

If you are completely new to Emacs, you might want to start out with Emacs Prelude or the Starter Kit:

- [Emacs Prelude](http://batsov.com/prelude/)
- [emacs-starter-kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit)

Comment: citizen428 link outdated

Comment: Does anyone happen to know which one is better, the ruby-mode.el that comes with Ruby or the one that comes with Emacs (24.4)? Emacs has that weird "smie" stuff...

Comment: @art-solopov ruby-mode.el in the Ruby repo has seen little development over the last years. SMIE is not weird, but you can still disable it.